# Unity Problem saying my Transformation Child is out of bound

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, parent-child

My overall goal was to create a basic inventory system for my game but my problem ended up with my entire inventory system crashing and not having anything I want.

So I deleted the code but it resulted in multiple other problems I tried to replace the code but it resulted in the same problem.

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public GameObject inventory;
    public GameObject slotHolder;
    private bool inventoryEnabled;
    private int slots;
    private Transform[] slot;
    private bool itemAdded;

    private GameObject itemPickedUp;

    public void Start()
    {
        // slots being detected

        slots = slotHolder.transform.childCount;
        slot = new Transform[slots];
        DetectInventorySlots();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            inventoryEnabled = !inventoryEnabled;
        }

        if (inventoryEnabled)
            inventory.SetActive(true);
        else
            inventory.SetActive(false);            
    }    

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<Item>())
        {
            itemPickedUp = other.gameObject;
            Additem(itemPickedUp);
        }
    }

    public void Additem(GameObject item)
    {
        for(int i = 0; 1  < slots; i ++)
        {
            if(slot[i].GetComponent<Slots>().empty)
            {
                slot[i].GetComponent<Slots>().item = itemPickedUp;
                slot[i].GetComponent<Slots>().itemIcon = itemPickedUp.GetComponent<Item>().icon;
                itemAdded = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void DetectInventorySlots()
    {
        for (int i = 0; 1 < slots; i++)
        {
            slot[i] = slotHolder.transform.GetChild(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the outcome to show my item in the inventory system but the actual outcome is the entire inventory system not working and shutting off.

Comment: please move your SetActive calls in Update to the { } after the if (Input.GetKeyDown) the way you are doing it now does exactly the same but more expensive. Not sure how to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `DetectInventorySlots` that leads to an infinite loop. You need to be comparing the variables `i` and `slots`, not the number `1` with `slots`.

It should be:

```
public void DetectInventorySlots()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < slots; i++)
    {
        slot[i] = slotHolder.transform.GetChild(i);
    }
}
```

not:

```
public void DetectInventorySlots()
{
    for (int i = 0; 1 < slots; i++)
    {
        slot[i] = slotHolder.transform.GetChild(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice spoted, its hard to see, if anyone wonders, its "i" versus "1"

Comment: @zambari Thanks. I edited my answer to indicate the difference.